# Irreducibility of $x^{p(p-1)}+x^{p(p-2)}+\cdots+x^p+1$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

It is well known that the $p$th cyclotomic polynomial
$$\Phi_p(x)\ =\ x^{p-1}+\cdots+x+1\ =\ \frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$$

is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ for prime $p$. The standard trick is to make the transformation $x\mapsto x+1$ and turn the polynomial to one of the form $x^{p-1}+p\cdot q(x)$, where $q(x)$ is polynomial of degree $p-2$ and constant term 1, and apply Eisenstein's criterion.

On p.35 of *The Theory of Algebraic Numbers* by Harry Pollard and Harold G. Diamond (Dover edition) the authors state that the following polynomial is also irreducible over $\mathbb Q$:
$$\Phi_p(x^p)\ =\ x^{p(p-1)}+\cdots+x^p+1\ =\ \frac{x^{p^2}-1}{x^p-1}$$

(where $p$, as before, is prime). According to the book the result can also be proved by applying the transformation $x\mapsto x+1$. I tried it but I'm afraid it got me nowhere; neither have I been able to prove it by any other method.

I would be grateful if someone could show me how it is done. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any commutative ring of characteristic $p$ we have $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$. Therefore, when reduced modulo $p$,
$$
\Phi_p((x+1)^p)=\frac{(x+1)^{p^2}-1}{(x+1)^p-1}\equiv\frac{x^{p^2}}{x^p}
=x^{p^2-p}.
$$
So all but the leading coefficient of $\Phi_p((x+1)^p)$ are divisible by $p$.

On the other hand $\Phi_p(1^p)=p$, so the constant term of $\Phi_p((x+1)^p)$
is not divisible by $p^2$. Eisenstein kicks in, and the irreducibility of $\Phi_p(x^p)$ follows.

Comment: Somewhat against my expectations I didn't find an earlier incarnation on the site. Will keep looking. Ping me, if you find one.

Comment: @Jryki Took only a few secs....

Comment: Thanks @Bill. Apparently I only tried wrong keywords back in the day. IIRC I didn't know about Approach0 back in '16. May be we didn't have it then?

Answer (score 2):

Well, $ \varphi(p^2) = p(p-1) $, so the $p^2 $-th cyclotomic polynomial is of degree $ p(p-1) $, monic, and it divides $ p(x) = (x^{p^2} - 1)/(x^p - 1) $, since any primitive $ p^2 $-th root of unity remains a root of this polynomial. This means that $ p(x) $ *is* the cyclotomic polynomial, and it is thus irreducible.

The idea of the transformation $ x \to x+1 $ is that the prime $ p $ totally ramifies in $ \mathbf Q(\zeta_{p^2}) $ as $ (p) = (1 - \zeta_{p^2})^{p(p-1)} $. It is then well-known that the characteristic polynomial of $ 1 - \zeta_{p^2} $ must be Eisenstein at $ p $, since it generates the prime ideal lying above $ p $.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another way of doing the same thing, very similar to what Jyrki has written:

It’s a little clearer, I think, to show that for $n\ge1$, $\Phi_{p^{n+1}}(X)=(X^{p^{n+1}}-1)\big/(X^{p^n}-1)$ is irreducible. We set $$g(X)=\Phi_p(1+X)=\frac{(1+X)^{\,p}-1}{X}\,,$$
clearly a monic polynomial of degree $p-1$, constant term $p$, all intermediate coefficients divisible by $p$. Now we have
\begin{align}
\Phi_{p^{n+1}}(X)&=\frac{X^{p^{n+1}}-1}{X^{p^n}-1}\\
\Phi_{p^{n+1}}(1+X)&=\frac{(1+X)^{p^{n+1}}-1}{(1+X)^{p^n}-1}\\
&=g\bigl[(1+X)^{p^n}-1\bigr]\,,
\end{align}
where what’s getting substituted into $g$ is a polynomial of degree $p^n$ without constant term, and in which all the terms but the highest one are divisible by $p$. That is, the last line can be written $g\bigl[pXh(X)+X^{p^n}\bigr]$, and since $g$ is Eisenstein, so is the last line of the display.

Comment: How do you know that $g(X)$ irreducible $\implies$ $g(\text{that polynomial})$ irreducible?

Comment: **1**. The constant is $p$. **2**. The very last line of my answer says that the result of the substitution is $\equiv(X^{p^n})^{p-1}$ modulo $p$.