# What's the easiest way to see that $(X+1)^{p(p-1)} + (X+1)^{p(p-2)} + \cdots + (X+1)^p + 1$ is $p$-Eisenstein?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

Consider the polynomial:

$$(X+1)^{p(p-1)} + (X+1)^{p(p-2)} + \cdots + (X+1)^p + 1$$

In Serre's local fields, he says that this polynomial is clearly Eisenstein, by noting that its constant term is $p$, and mod $p$ it is equal to $X^{p(p-1)}$.

It's clear that it's constant term is $p$, but it is far less clear to me that mod $p$ it is just $X^{p(p-1)}$. I've reduced it to showing that for any $0 < i < p$, the sum $\binom{p-1}{i} + \binom{p-2}{i-1} + \cdots + \binom{p-1-i}{0}$ is divisible by $p$, but this is hardly obvious to me.

Is there a better way to see that all the non-leading terms vanish mod $p$?

Comment: Related [Irreducibility of $x^{p(p-1)}+x^{p(p-2)}+\cdots+x^p+1$ over $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899185/irreducibility-of-xpp-1xpp-2-cdotsxp1-over-mathbb-q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $$u^p- 1 = (u - 1 )(u^{p-1} + \cdots +1),$$ and $$ (x+1)^p \equiv x^p + 1 \pmod p,$$along with the fact that ${\mathbb F}_p[x]$ is a UFD.

*Edit:*

As Darij points out below, one does not need to use the UFDhoodshipness of ${\mathbb F}_p[x]$. For any (commutative) ring $R$, multiplication by $x$ is (visibly!) injective on the polynomial ring $R[x]$:

Set
$$ q(x) = (x+1)^{p(p-1)}+ \cdots + 1. $$
The argument sketched above (the 2 equalities) gives the equality in $ {\mathbb F}_p[x]$ 
$$  x^{p^2} = x^p q(x).$$
Therefore, by the injectivity by multiplication by $x$ in the polynomial ring,  $$q(x) = x^{p^2-p}.$$

Comment: Why do you need the UFDness?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks - I addressed your comment above. I had in the back of my mind, (if indeed there was anything in the back of it, or if I have a mind at all) the likes of $x^2 = (x-2)^2$  in ${\mathbb Z}/(4)[x]$.

Comment: @stupid_question_bot see Darij's comment and my subsequent edit. BTW, I remember not believing the calculation of Chapter V, Section 3, Proposition 5, although I could 'correct' it to get the result. On the other hand, I have been wrong before, and (cough) there is some evidence that Serre is smarter than me - but beware?